# Conjecture: $\pi(x)\ge \pi\circ\pi(x)+\pi\circ\pi\circ\pi(x)+\cdots$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

> $x\ge 13\implies\pi(x)\ge \pi\circ\pi(x)+\pi\circ\pi\circ\pi(x)+\cdots$

Can this be proved?

Comment: Does $\pi\circ\pi(x)$ mean $\pi(\pi(x)) $?

Comment: This isn't a proof but this was my first thought: Replace Pi(x) by (1/2)*x-a since the around half of the numbers up to x are even primes and the a would just correct this expression to be equal to Pi(x). Then what you end up getting is (1/2 )*x-a >= (1/2)((1/2)x-a)-b + (1/2)((1/2)((1/2)x-a)-b)-c) which seems like it is  true since 1/2= 1/4+1/8+1/16...

Comment: Maybe an idea about the sum :
We know that $\pi(x) < 4/3\cdot  x/\ln(x)$. Also we have $4/3 \cdot 1/\ln(12) < 3/5$ therefore for $x > 12,\ \pi(x) < 3/5x$. The sum on the RHS can be bounded : $\sum_{i=2}^\infty \pi^{\circ^i}(x) < \sum_{i=2}^\infty (\frac{3}{5})^i x = 9/10x$. Also it exists lower-linear bound for $\pi(x)$. So maybe refining a bit this technique and putting the two bounds together could lead to something.

Comment: (Actually I don't think it exists lower-linear bound, sorry about that, I was thinking about something $0.9 x/\ln(x) < \pi(x)$ which does not work since $x$ can grow)

Comment: It is true up to $x=2000$.

Comment: @Deepak: yes, it means the composition of functions.

Comment: I think your best approach is to use bounds from the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).  Use lower bounds on the right and an upper bound on the left.  If we just use the naive $\pi(x) \approx \frac n{\log x}$ you are asking for $\frac 1{\log x} \gt \frac 1{\log x \cdot ( \log x -\log \log x)}+\ldots$ and that factor of $\log^2 x$ in the denominator should be enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inequality is trivially true because from the prime number theorem, the LHS is asymptotic to $\frac{x}{\log x}$ where as the RHS is asymptotic to $\frac{x}{\log^2 x}$ so clearly this is a very weak inequality and is has to be true for all $x$ greater than some minimum value which in this case turns to be 13.

What would make the inequality non-trivial is if the LHS and RHS are of the same asymptotic order.  I present a stronger form of the above inequality.

Let $s(x) = \pi(\pi(x)) + \pi(\pi(\pi(x))) + \ldots $.

[Pierre Dusart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf) has proved that
$$
\pi(x) \ge \frac{x}{\log x - 1}, \ x > 5393
$$

$$
\pi(x) \le \frac{x}{\log x - 1.1}, \ x > 60,184
$$

From these two inequalities and  little algebraic manipulation we obtain

$$
\frac{x}{(\log x - 1)(\log x - 2)} < s(x) < \frac{x}{(\log x - \log\log x)(\log x - \log\log x - 1)}
$$

or in the slightly weaker but simpler form

$$
\frac{x}{(\log x - 1)^2} < s(x) < \frac{x}{(\log x - \log\log x - 1)^2}
$$

for all $x > 60,184$. Clearly the RHS is less than $\pi(x)$ so the weaker original inequality follows.

Comment: The asymptotic behavior of $\pi(x)$ doesn't by itself make the inequality true, even for large $x$.  For instance, if you had $\pi(1)=1$ instead of $\pi(1)=0$... a very small change at very small $x$... then the sum on the RHS would diverge instead.

Comment: Yes, but in this specific case we already knew that $\pi(1) = 0$ hence the argument.

Answer (score 12):

Certainly $\pi(x) \le (2/3)x$ for all $x$, so the right-hand side satisfies
$$
\pi(\pi(x)) + \pi(\pi(\pi(x))) + \pi(\pi(\pi(\pi(x)))) + \ldots \le \pi(\pi(x))\left(1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{9}+\ldots\right)=3\pi(\pi(x)).
$$
Using the inequality $\pi(x) < 1.25506 (x / \ln x)$, then, we have
$$
3\pi(\pi(x))\le(1.25506\cdot 3 / \ln(\pi(x)))\pi(x) < \pi(x)
$$
provided that $\ln(\pi(x)) > 3.76518$, or $\pi(x)\ge44$, or $x \ge p_{44}=191$.  And a direct numerical check shows your inequality holds for $13\le x<191$.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, something more general can be proven:

$$n \geq \pi(n) + \pi(\pi(n))+ \pi(\pi(\pi(n))) + \cdots$$

First, note that $\pi(n) \leq \frac23n$ for all $n$. Also, note that $\pi(n) \leq \frac13n$ for $n \geq 35$.

**Proof.**  $\pi(n) \leq \frac12n+1$ for all $n$ follows from the fact that two is the only even prime.  This is smaller than $\frac23n$ for all $n\geq 6$. It can be checked manually for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.

For the second inequality, note that every prime not equal to $2,3$ is congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $6$. Now note that $1, 25$ and $35$ do have this form, but are not prime. From this, we also have $\pi(n) \leq \frac13n$ for $n \geq 35$.

---

Now the main proof:

Let $f^k$ denote function iteration. We have for $n\geq35$ that $$\pi^k(n) = \pi^{k-1}(\pi(n)) \leq \pi^{k-1}\left(\frac13n\right) \leq \left(\frac23\right)^{k-1}\cdot \left(\frac13n\right)$$

Hence we have the inequality $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \pi^i(n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac13\left(\frac23\right)^{i-1}n = \frac13n \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac23\right)^{i-1} = \frac13n \cdot \frac1{1-\frac23}=n$$

Now, substituting $n=\pi(x)$ gives the desired result for $x \geq 149$.

Another user already showed this for $13\leq x \leq 2000$, so this gives the result.